# Can make a deep copy of an object to an already existing object in C#

Tags: c#, deep-copy

I know I can Deep Copy by accessing one property at a time and copying it. But is there a way where I can deep copy an entire object on one go? Assume I cannot alter the class `Sample`.

```
 Class Sample{
  int a;
  int b;
  public int A {get => A; set => A = value}
  public int B {get => B; set => B = value}
 }


Sample sm1 = new Sample();
Sample sm2 = sm1;
sm2.A = 5;
sm1 = sm2 //DeepCopy
```

Comment: This has been asked lots of times.

Comment: @TheGeneral most of them involve altering the `Sample` class. :/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects check out the json ones, Also you could use automapper if you are already using it (though that can be a little smelly)

Comment: Note thar 'deep-copy' is not a well-defined thing but will always involve deciding on the level of depth to go to when cloning.